# How to align wrapped text with non wrapped text on the same line using Report lab in python

Tags: python, reportlab

I am creating a pdf with help of reportLab module in Python. I applied word wrap on each column to adjust the text. But I am not getting the wrapped text and non wrapped text on the same line.
Actual output:

[image]

Expected:
[image]

#!/usr/local/bin/python

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, inch, landscape
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("test.pdf", pagesize=A4, rightMargin=30,leftMargin=30, topMargin=30,bottomMargin=18)
doc.pagesize = landscape(A4)
elements = []

data = [
["Letters code with num test", "Number", "Long stuff that should be wrapped1", "Long stuff that should be wrapped"],
["A", "01", "ABCD", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"],
["B", "02", "CDEF", "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"],
["C", "03", "SDFSDF", "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC"],
["D", "04", "SDFSDF", "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD"],
["E", "05", "GHJGHJGHJ", "EEEEEEEEEEEEEE EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE"],
]

#TODO: Get this line right instead of just copying it from the docs
style = TableStyle([('ALIGN',(1,1),(-2,-2),'RIGHT'),                     
                      ('VALIGN',(0,0),(0,-1),'TOP'),                        
                       ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                       ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                       ])

#Configure style and word wrap
s = getSampleStyleSheet()
s = s["BodyText"]
s.wordWrap = 'CJK'
data2 = [[Paragraph(cell, s) for cell in row] for row in data]
t=Table(data2)
t.setStyle(style)

#Send the data and build the file
elements.append(t)
doc.build(elements)
```

How to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I added  ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'TOP') on the table style. its working now.

Working code:

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, inch, landscape
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("test.pdf", pagesize=A4, rightMargin=30,leftMargin=30, topMargin=30,bottomMargin=18)
doc.pagesize = landscape(A4)
elements = []

data = [
["Letters code with num test", "Number", "Long stuff that should be wrapped1", "Long stuff that should be wrapped"],
["A", "01", "ABCD", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"],
["B", "02", "CDEF", "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"],
["C", "03", "SDFSDF", "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC"],
["D", "04", "SDFSDF", "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD"],
["E", "05", "GHJGHJGHJ", "EEEEEEEEEEEEEE EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE"],
]

#TODO: Get this line right instead of just copying it from the docs
style = TableStyle([('ALIGN',(1,1),(-2,-2),'RIGHT'),                     
                      ('VALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'TOP'),                        
                       ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                       ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                       ])

#Configure style and word wrap
s = getSampleStyleSheet()
s = s["BodyText"]
s.wordWrap = 'CJK'
data2 = [[Paragraph(cell, s) for cell in row] for row in data]
t=Table(data2)
t.setStyle(style)

#Send the data and build the file
elements.append(t)
doc.build(elements)
```